# Is there a maximum number of characters that can be passed within one positional parameter in bash?

Tags: bash, parameters, limit

I have a a variable which is a list (can have 10.000 characters) which I want to send as one positional parameter when calling some script. So I wonder is there a maximum number of characters that can be send this way?

The other option would be to save it in some file that will be read by this script, but from some reasons, first scenario may be easier for implementation.

It is RedHat OS.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless RedHat alters this, which I doubt, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument a single argument is limited to 128k (4k x 32) and all arguments plus envvars combined is (POSIXly) limited to sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX) which is 1/4 of ulimit -s but not less than 128k, and also limited by ulimit -s (necessarily, since they must be stored there). The thing exec'ed (here your script) can also have limits or restrictions, of course.`man execve` should document this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On modern linux, the maximum length of a single argument is `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` which is probably 131072 bytes:

**/usr/include/linux/binfmts.h:**

```
#define MAX_ARG_STRLEN (PAGE_SIZE * 32)
```

**/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/user.h:**

```
#define PAGE_SHIFT              12
#define PAGE_SIZE               (1UL << PAGE_SHIFT)
```

See also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument
- [https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/argmax/)

Comment: That should be more then enough for what I need. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in limit to the operating system, on how much data can be  passed to a child process. You can query this value from the command line using

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

This value comprises the total length over all arguments plus the environment.
There is no additional restriction for a **single** argument, but it means that if you have an unreasonably large environment, and want to pass many arguments to a process, this reduces the allowed size of a single argument.

In addition, there seems to be a maximum limit for a single argument, but this value can't be queried by `getconf` directly. However, there exists the configuration value for `PAGE_SIZE`, and it is until now a common convention to guarantee a argument size of at least 32 times this value. Hence a heuristic calculation  for this limit would be

```
printf %d $((32 * $(getconf PAGE_SIZE) ))
```

Comment: I think you are incorrect that "there is no additional restriction for a single argument". linux does impose an additional restriction: `/bin/echo $(printf %0131072d)` vs `/bin/echo $(printf %0131071d) $(printf %0131071d) | wc -c`

Comment: @jhnc: I don't have a Linux at hand, but tried it on MacOS. The first one succeeds, but the second one yields _argument argument list too long_, which is not surprising, because on my system ARG_MAX happens to be 262144 and your second command produces a total argument length of exactly this value as well; since we also have to add space for the environment (and the terminating 0-byte for the argument strings), we are clearly over the limit.

Comment: @jhnc : Ah, I just found it. Will update my question accordingly.